# else if loops do not stop when radio button is not checked, next activity opens anyway

Tags: java, android

I'm quite new to coding in Android Studio and have produced a symptom checker that allows a user to check a series of yes and no radio buttons to answer questions. The problem is that even if one questions (yes and no) radio buttons are missed a 'toast' notification that I produced pops up but doesnt stop the user from reaching the next activity (diagnosis page).

I have tried using the return; command to try and stop the loop but it still does the same thing. If all questions are answered this does not become a problem.

The application can be accessed from this link: github.com/Akhlz001/MHT_Application

Here is part of the activity code showing two of the loops (these loops are repeated 9 times):

```
public void opendiagnosis() {

    if (radioButton.isChecked())
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, answers.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if (radioButton2.isChecked())
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, answers.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please answer all the questions for an accurate diagnosis",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if (radioButton3.isChecked())
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, answers.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if (radioButton4.isChecked())
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, answers.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please answer all the questions for an accurate diagnosis",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
```

An insight on what the problem is would be really helpful, thank you.

Comment: Where is the loop code?

Comment: Is the xml file needed? Otherwise the problem I'm having is that the 'intent' (intent being the next activity) is still triggered even if the loop reaches the 'else' part.

Comment: Since I can't see anything like "while" or "for", I suppose "loop" does not mean the same thing for everybody? That being said, if your user did not check radioButtons 3 and 4 you will show a Toast. At the same time, if the user did check radioButton2, the next Activity will be started. And you only want to proceed to the next Activity if for all pairs of RadioButtons a selection has been made, correct?

Comment: Yes that is exactly it

Comment: you put on the code in github, it is more easy to undertand what happend.

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/Akhlz001/MHT_Application

Comment: The problem is in the questions.java file linked to the activity_questions.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only want to proceed to the next `Activity` if for all pairs of `RadioButton`s a selection has been made. So you can change your code as follows:

```
public void opendiagnosis() {
    // for all pairs: one of each pair has to be checked
    boolean shouldStartNextActivity = (radioButton.isChecked() || radioButton2.isChecked())
            && (radioButton3.isChecked() || radioButton4.isChecked());


    if (shouldStartNextActivity){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, answers.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please answer all the questions for an accurate diagnosis", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next

```
package com.note.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.RadioGroup
import android.widget.Toast


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val radioGroup = findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.opciones_pago)
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext," On checked change : $group",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    }
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/opciones_pago"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_deposito"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Depósito directo" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_paypal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="Paypal" />
    </RadioGroup>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

if you put on the code in github, it is more easy to undertand what happend.